# Fill the region bounded by three points

Tags: tikz-pgf

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{wrwrwr}{rgb}{0.3803921568627451,0.3803921568627451,0.3803921568627451}
\definecolor{rvwvcq}{rgb}{0.08235294117647059,0.396078431372549,0.7529411764705882}
\definecolor{sexdts}{rgb}{0.1803921568627451,0.49019607843137253,0.19607843137254902}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=1cm,y=1cm,
axis lines=middle,
axis line style={stealth-stealth},
xmin=-6,
xmax=6,
ymin=-6,
ymax=6,
xtick={-5,...,5},
ytick={-5,-4,...,5},]
\draw [samples=50,rotate around={0:(0,0)},xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm,line width=0.8pt,color=sexdts,domain=-4:4,<->,name path=C1] plot (\x,{(\x)^2/2/2});
\draw [line width=0.5pt,color=rvwvcq,<->,name path=C2] (2,-3.) -- (2,5.);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.8pt);
\draw[color=black] (0.30,-0.30) node [rotate=00]{O};
\draw [fill=black] (2,1) circle (1.8pt);
\draw[color=black] (2.40,0.8) node {B};
\draw [fill=black] (2,0) circle (1.8pt);
\draw[color=black] (2.30,-0.40) node [rotate=00]{A};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Question: How can i fill the region which is covered by three coordinates `O(0,0)` , `A(2,0)` and `B(2,1)` by different colors with various opacity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by different colours with different opacity? With only one color, we have this.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{wrwrwr}{rgb}{0.3803921568627451,0.3803921568627451,0.3803921568627451}
\definecolor{rvwvcq}{rgb}{0.08235294117647059,0.396078431372549,0.7529411764705882}
\definecolor{sexdts}{rgb}{0.1803921568627451,0.49019607843137253,0.19607843137254902}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\begin{axis}[
x=1cm,y=1cm,
axis lines=middle,
axis line style={stealth-stealth},
xmin=-6,
xmax=6,
ymin=-6,
ymax=6,
xtick={-5,...,5},
ytick={-5,-4,...,5},]
\draw [samples=50,rotate around={0:(0,0)},xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm,line width=0.8pt,color=sexdts,domain=-4:4,<->,name path=C1] plot (\x,{(\x)^2/2/2});
\draw [line width=0.5pt,color=rvwvcq,<->,name path=C2] (2,-3.) -- (2,5.);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.8pt);
\draw[color=black] (0.30,-0.30) node [rotate=00]{O};
\draw [fill=black] (2,1) circle (1.8pt);
\draw[color=black] (2.40,0.8) node {B};
\draw [fill=black] (2,0) circle (1.8pt);
\draw[color=black] (2.30,-0.40) node [rotate=00]{A};

\path [name path=B]
(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) --
(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);
\addplot[orange,opacity=.5] fill between [
of=C1 and B,
soft clip={domain=0:2},
];
\end{scriptsize}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: fill]

Comment: I mean transparency or Darkness

Comment: @snehal like this ? `\addplot[orange,opacity=.5]`

Comment: Yes, exactly. Can you give another solution for better understanding. I am fully agree and happy with previous one.

Comment: @snehal like this ?

Comment: Yes. Exactly this. Is there any another way to fill region with color? I am just asking for knowledge.

Comment: @snehal you can do `[orange!50]` or `[orange!50!black]` etc